# Amplify, ionic. mobile HUB and api gateway authorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic2, aws-amplify

I configured amplify in a ionic project which has been tied to a mobilehub project.

The apis have been created using the serverless framework:

```
functions:
  device:
      handler: handler.device
      events:
        - http:
            path: devices
            method: get
            authorizer: aws_iam
        - http:
            path: devices
            method: put
            authorizer: aws_iam
        - http:
            path: devices
            method: post
            authorizer: aws_iam
        - http:
            path: devices
            method: delete
            authorizer: aws_iam
```

The APIs work and to my knowledge are tied to my cognito user pools. In fact, when I call a get on that API, I get a "missing token" message.

I am trying to implement the API call in an Ionic application. The application is the Ionic `aws` template, so it is able to login to cognito without problems.

I downloaded the 'aws-exports.js' file from the mobilehub page, included in my sources and imported

```
import awsmobile from '../../aws-exports';
import Amplify, { API } from 'aws-amplify';

ionViewDidLoad(){

    Amplify.configure(awsmobile);
    console.log(Amplify);

    let apiName = 'dev-parameters';
    let path = '/devices';

    API.get(apiName, path).then(response => {

      debugger;
      console.log(response);
    });
```

}

However I can see from the http calls that are made that an `OPTIONS` call is made that returns 403.

Request:

```
:method GET
:authority  cx1smjqtj5.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
:scheme https
:path   /dev/devices
user-agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36 OPR/50.0.2762.67
upgrade-insecure-requests   1
accept      text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=    0.8
accept-encoding gzip, deflate, br
accept-language en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
```

Response:

```
{
    "message": "Missing Authentication Token"
}
```

I really don't understand what I am missing or doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct in this configuration. I was able to make it work by compiling the aws-export.js (after renaming it aws-exports.ts) in typescript. After that the API calls are authenticated correctly.

`tsc aws-export.ts` generates a new aws-exports.js an the module is the imported correctly.